# getElementsByTagName.textContent returns undefined

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a XML file

```
<lle:Event>
      <lle:eventid>ID01</lle:eventid>
      <lle:collab>
        <lle:name>Jane Doe</lle:name>
        <lle:support>Carer</lle:support>
        <lle:supportTime>8am - 8pm</lle:supportTime>
        <lle:location>
          <lle:lat>1.3117216424564617</lle:lat>
          <lle:lng>103.8149642944336</lle:lng>
        </lle:location>
      </lle:collab>
    </lle:Event>
    <lle:Event>
      <lle:eventid>ID02</lle:eventid>
      <lle:collab>
        <lle:name>Peter Smith</lle:name>
        <lle:support>Carer</lle:support>
        <lle:supportTime>8am - 8pm</lle:supportTime>
        <lle:location>
          <lle:lat>1.3772782313341114</lle:lat>
          <lle:lng>103.89873504638672</lle:lng>
        </lle:location>
      </lle:collab>
    </lle:Event>
    <lle:Event>
      ...
    </lle:Event>
        <lle:Event>
      <lle:eventid>ID08</lle:eventid>
      <lle:collab>
        <lle:name>Ang</lle:name>
        <lle:support>Doctor</lle:support>
        <lle:supportTime>8am - 8pm</lle:supportTime>
        <lle:img>avatar.png</lle:img>
        <lle:location>
          <lle:lat>1.3577459437939223</lle:lat>
          <lle:lng>103.84522878271483</lle:lng>
        </lle:location>
      </lle:collab>
    </lle:Event>
```

Some lle:Event has lle:img element while some don't.

I am trying to differentiate them using javascript in order to use a custom image marker on Google map for those with lle:img element.

```
var events = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("lle:Event");
                         console.log(events);
                         for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                             
                             var name = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("lle:name")[i].textContent;
                             var support = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("lle:support")[i].textContent;
                             var supportTime = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("lle:supportTime")[i].textContent;
                             var lat = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("lle:lat")[i].textContent;
                             var lng = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("lle:lng")[i].textContent;

                             latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                             
                           
                             if (events[i].getElementsByTagName("lle:img").length > 0 ) {
                                 var imgPath = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("lle:img")[i].textContent;
                                 console.log(imgPath);
                                 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                     position: latLng,
                                     map,
                                     title: "Name: " + name + "\nSupport: " + support + "\nSupport Time: " + supportTime,
                                     
                                 });
                             } else if (!events[i].getElementsByTagName("lle:img").length > 0) {
                                
                                 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                     position: latLng,
                                     map,
                                     title: "Name: " + name + "\nSupport: " + support + "\nSupport Time: " + supportTime,
                                 });
                             }
```

In the above, I check for whether lle:img exist using

```
events[i].getElementsByTagName("lle:img").length > 0
```

However when i try to get imgPath with getElementsByTagName("lle:img")[i].textContent with

```
var imgPath = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("lle:img")[i].textContent;
```

the console.log results always shows undefined.

Im very sure the the lle:img element is there but somehow it is still returning undefined. Is there anything wrong that im doing here?

Comment: maybe you could check if the return value of `getElementsByTagName` is what it should be

Comment: @OtherMe I did check that all the getElementsByTagName before the if else returns the correct value. Only the one which is trying to get "lle:img" is giving me undefined.

Comment: why do you go from searching in the current `event` to search the entire document?  Unless every `event` has exactly 1 "lle:img", your index of [i] will be incorrect

Comment: also, in your else condition is troubling. It probably works by sheer luck, but you already checked in your `if` condition, so no need to check again in your `else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you check in your `if`

`events[i].getElementsByTagName("lle:img").length`

and this is what you use to set imgPath

`xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("lle:img")[i].textContent`

see the difference?
In particular, `i` is the index to the event. It makes no sense to use it to index the "lle:img" elements. You presumably have fewer "lle:img" elements than events, so your index is out of range.

Your `else` condition is also buggy. It probably works because `!...length` will be `true` when length is 0, and true > 0, but that's just lucky. You don't need it at all.

try this

```
if (events[i].getElementsByTagName("lle:img").length > 0 ) {
    var imgPath = events[i].getElementsByTagName("lle:img")[0].textContent;
    console.log(imgPath);
    ...

} else {
    ...
}
```

better yet, reduce the number of times you parse it and save your found elements:

```
var images = events[i].getElementsByTagName("lle:img")
if (images.length > 0) {
    var imgPath = images[0].textContent
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's what it was! The index was out of range which is why the value is returned is undefined. The explaination really helped alot! It is working now. Thanks alot!